# How can I merge old data with new data

Tags: python, sqlite

Hi I currently want to show the product cart to the customer which means i need to get the data from the old table which are the products and the new table which is the quanity of the product that they want but when the data is inserted it acts as 2 different things so it does not merge, this is the code that i have thus far;

```
def add_to_productcart():
    while True:
        buyername = str(input("Please Enter Your Username: "))
        print("="*25)
        print(f"{buyername}'s Product Cart")
        print("="*25)
        ProductID = str(input("Please Enter ProductID that you want to buy: "))
        with sqlite3.connect(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\HFSystem\Assginment\HFuserinfo.db") as connect:
                cursor = connect.cursor()      
        idcheck = """SELECT *FROM products WHERE ProductID = ?"""
        idchecked = cursor.execute(idcheck,[ProductID])

        if (idchecked):
            
            Quantity = int(input("Enter the Quantity You Want: "))
            Totalprice = 0
            first=("""INSERT INTO productcarts(Buyername,Quantity,Totalprice)VALUES(?,?,?)""")
            cursor.execute(first,[buyername,Quantity,Totalprice])

            products = """INSERT INTO productcarts
                (ProductID,
                ProductName,
                ProductPrice,
                Produced,
                ExpiryDate)
                SELECT ProductID,
                ProductName,
                ProductPrice,
                Produced,
                ExpiryDate
                FROM products WHERE ProductID = ?
                """

            added = cursor.execute(products,[ProductID])
            connect.commit()
            
            if (added):
                print(f"Product{ProductID} added into {buyername}'s cart")
                productcart_menu()
            else:
                print(f"Product{ProductID} failed to add into {buyername}'s cart")
                productcart_menu()
                connect.close()    
        else:
            print(f"Product{ProductID} not found! Please Try Again!")
            return productcart_menu()
```

I realised the error is that i have 2 executes so that the data inserted does not act as a whole but when i changed it i keep getting errors, any suggestions are welcomed thank you.

Comment: For one thing, the `with` statement closes the connection as soon as you leave it, at which point your `cursor` is no longer valid

Comment: More generally, try the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) guide?